# How to get payload of http request (soap) using apache cxf. Missing envelope closure while using interceptor

Tags: java, spring, apache, cxf, interceptor

Im trying to append custom header into cxf Message, and it works, but i have some issue with Message payload.

```
public HttpHeaderInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.USER_PROTOCOL);
}

public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {

    try {

        Map<String, List<String>> headers = (HashMap<String, List<String>>) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);

        if(validationFlag){

        headerInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
        String messageContent="empty";
        OutputStream os = message.getContent(OutputStream.class);
        StringBuilder responsePayload = new StringBuilder();
        CachedOutputStream cos = (CachedOutputStream) os;
        try {
            cos.writeCacheTo(responsePayload);
            messageContent = IOUtils.toString(cos.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


            //here im getting hashCode of message payload and add to header
            byte[] messageByte = messageContent.getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] doFinal = mac.doFinal(messageByte);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(" Checksum:");
            sb.append(Hex.encodeHex(doFinal));

            headerInfo.add(scValidationCode);
            headerInfo.add(sb.toString());
            headers.put("Warning", headerInfo);
        }

    } catch ( Exception e) {
        throw new Fault(e);
    }
}
```

In this fragment :

```
messageContent = IOUtils.toString(cos.getInputStream());
```

messageContent is equal for example:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:someNamespace xmlns:ns2="http://something.com>some Soap request body</ns2:someNamespace>
```

but the orginal full request payload is equal:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:someNamespace xmlns:ns2="http://something.com>some Soap request body</ns2:someNamespace></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

So in my messageContent i've got lost `</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`. 
I have tried changing org.apache.cxf.phase Phase but still my payload from Message is without soap envelope closure.

I don't have any idea why when i'm trying to get message.getContent(OutputStream.class)  im loosing ONLY soap closure. 
Anything else is working good. The HTTP header is appending new value.

Answer (score 2):

ok i have passed through almost all cxf chain and i found out solution.

The soap envelope and body closure, are being add in soap SoapOutInterceptor but in subclass exactly in SoapOutEndingInterceptor from ENDING chain.

So if you want to have full payload with soap closure you have to put your custom interceptor in two ways:

```
super(Phase.PRE_STREAM_ENDING);
addBefore(StaxOutInterceptor.StaxOutEndingInterceptor.class.getName());
```

or the second way:

```
super(Phase.WRITE_ENDING);
addAfter(SoapOutInterceptor.SoapOutEndingInterceptor.class.getName());
```

Have fun!